# Recursive Function java

Tags: java, recursion

Question 1

Write a recursive function that returns the product of the even numbers between 1 and n.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int n=0; n<10; n++)
    { 
         System.out.println("f("+n+") = "+fact(n));
    }
}

public static int fact(int number)
{
    if(number==2)
        return 1;
    else
    {
         if(number%2==0)
             return number*fact(number-1);
         else
         {
             return fact(number-1);
         }
    }
}
```

Not sure where i do wrong here. Please help..thanks.

Comment: If you have a problem with your code, then explain what exactly happens. Do you get a compiler error? Or an exception? Is the result wrong?

Comment: The question is not describing a facturation but a different problem. You code looks more like facturation. You would simply do return number*fact(number-2); The start value of number==2 is 2 not one. You then need to decide if you want to accept odd numbers at all and adjust the loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
if(number==2)
    return 2;
```

you should also handle `number==0` and `number==1`, such as:

```
    if(number==0)
        return 1; //or 0, it depends on what you want
    else if(number==2)
        return 2;
    else
    {
         if(number%2==0)
             return number*fact(number-1);
         else
         {
             return fact(number-1);
         }
    }
```

Comment: I changed it to 2 but i'm still having error in netbeans.

Comment: @user3807187 you should also handle `number==0` and `number==1`

Answer (score 0):

When number=0 it calls fact(-1) --> fact(number-1)

when number=1 it calls fact(0) and then fact(-1) ... fact(-x)

Answer (score 0):

the base is the fact of 2 which = 2 not 1

public static int fact(int number){

```
   if(number==2)
       return 2;
   else
       return (number%2==0) ? number*fact(number-1): fact(number-1);

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple if you think recursively :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 10;//Or whatever you want your N to be
         System.out.println("f("+n+") = "+recursiveEvenProduct(2, n));
}

public static int recursiveEvenProduct(int low, int n)
{
    if(low <= n-2)//Or (low <= n-3) if you don't want to include n
        return low *= recursiveEvenProduct(low+2, n);
    return low;
}
```

That is just one of the ways to do it. I'm sure you can think more ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int productOfEvens(int n)
{
    if (n > 1)
        if (n%2 == 0)
            return n *= productOfEvens(n-1);
        else 
            return productOfEvens(n-1);
    return 1;
}
```

This method is invoked, at first by another method and then recursively by itself, n-1 times with n being reduced by 1 in every recursive invocation, until it is reduced down to 2. Then it recursively returns to N, having collected all the values of the even numbers it passed, multiplied recursively. Because results quickly get huge, you can use long instead of int.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can call directly `return number*fact(number-2);` as you only want even numbers

```
if(number==0) {
        return 1; //or 0, it depends on what you want
    } else if(number==2){
        return 2;
    } else {
         if(number%2==0) {
             return number*fact(number-2);
         } else {
             return fact(number-1);
         }
    }
```